# Identify when a TCP socket is opened with inotify

Tags: inotify

As the title suggests, is there a way of being notified of recently opened sockets using inotify/inotify-tools? As far as I can tell inotify only works with inodes and specifically testing if those inodes are sockets isn't something that inotify is actually capable of. Further to that, I can't seem to find where sockets FD's are stored. I can only see their file descriptors which are symlinks:

```
# ls -l /proc/29711/fd/10 
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  6 17:04 /proc/29711/fd/10 -> socket:[750728]

# stat /proc/29711/fd/10
  File: `/proc/29711/fd/10' -> `socket:[750728]'
  Size: 64              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   symbolic link
Device: 3h/3d   Inode: 759700      Links: 1
Access: (0700/lrwx------)  Uid: ( 0/    root)   Gid: ( 0/    root)
Access: 2013-03-06 17:05:22.690411801 +1100
Modify: 2013-03-06 17:04:14.062414880 +1100
Change: 2013-03-06 17:04:14.062414880 +1100
 Birth: -
```

Comment: don't forget `proc filesystem` is a logical filesystem. So it doesn't support same softlink or hardlink in `real filesystem`.ext family, reiserfs , ufs and so on are real filesystem.`sysfs` is `logical filesystem`.Indeed `logical filesystems` are working with memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inotify is for filesystem events monitoring, so unless there is special FS representing system's sockets — no way.

I recommend looking at [netlink](http://linux.die.net/man/7/netlink) and at its `NETLINK_INET_DIAG` in particular, but I can't tell for sure whether it has corresponding facilities at all.

**UPDATE:** I've [shared](https://plus.google.com/u/0/109796411674599565310/posts/Ui9wMg1h8mL) this question-answer and Pavel Emelyanov — [CRIU](http://criu.org/)'s primarily developer, confirmed my suspicions — more than likely you can't get those notifications with `netlink`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: you can track these events with [conntrack-tools](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/).